# Measurement of the quality of finite non-diffracting beam

Tags: optics, waves, diffraction

All sorts of non-diffracting beams have been observed nowadays, e.g., the classic finite Airy beam (by [Siviloglou et. al. [2007]](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.99.213901)). In the past decade, lots of variants of finite Airy beam appear, which is also accelerating and contains finite energy. But in most papers, the different non-diffracting beams are compared only visually. My question is, is there a clear benchmark, or any physical quantity that describes how non-diffracting a certain beam is?